# How do I copy formatted HTML string into a Clipboard for paste using C#?

Tags: c#

My ultimate objective is to [Insert formatted rich text into Outlook inspector (e.g. AppointmentItem, MailItem, etc).](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsto/thread/18945426-c422-4c6e-9e58-94e3fd7b31c4?prof=required)  I asked this question on MSDN forums, and somebody replied I should use Clipboard to its copy contents, then Paste it in the window using hte target formatting I want to use.

I have the following HTML **string**

```
<html><body><table><tr><td>iPhone</td><td>Telephone#</td></tr></table></body></html>
```

And I have the following C# code

```
Clipboard.SetText(insertString, TextDataFormat.Html);

//....
//code to get Word.Range in my inspector item (inconsequential to this question)
//....

selected.Paste();
```

The problem is that the Clipboard doesn't insert the text, or throws a COM Failed exception in the code.

[image: COM exception when using Paste()]

**ANSWER thanks to jlew**

```
 HtmlFragment.CopyToClipboard(insertString);
 selected.Paste();
```

HtmlFragment code found here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2007/01/21/sample-code-html-clipboard.aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unless something has changed since the olden days (.NET 2, which was the last time I tried this) you need to add the proper clipboard header lines before putting it on the clipboard, as described here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2007/01/21/html-clipboard.aspx