# excel vba: coping cell with hyperlink formula fails when copy from one the another excel instance

Tags: excel, hyperlink, vba

When I copy a cell, what includes a hyperlink formula, it is insert as a html link as formatted by the formula. That only works as long as the receiving applications is not another Excel 2010 instance/application object.
When I copy it from the origin instance to another instance, it copies only plain text.

Can I write code what put a html formatted text in the clipboard instead of *Excel cell content object*?

Comment: Please share the code that you're currently using.

Comment: it is not really a code just a formula `=HYPERLINK(E10;C2 & "_" & C8 & "_" & TEXT(C4;"000") )`. I do copy (origin doc) / paste (different instance). I played a bit with code but without any success so far.

Comment: Please show what you've tried.  I am not seeing an issue with simply copy/pasting links between Excel document, provided you are appropriately hyperlinking.  I would suggest creating the hyperlink in VBA so the output in the cell is just a hyperlink, not a formula.  That should fix the issue (e.g., range("name").formula=application.hyperlink(blah)).

Comment: try to copy from one instance to another instance of Excel, than you see it.
When you open the task manager there have to be twice EXCEL.EXE

Comment: My suggestion would still stand.  Don't allow the cell itself to say the formula, just the actual hyperlink.  There's a disconnect between a formula versus an actual hyperlink, where the formula is a single string, but the actual hyperlink is an array with both a destination and a label.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't really understand what you mean. All what I have is cell containing this formula: `=HYPERLINK(E10;C2 & "_" & C8 & "_" & TEXT(C4;"000") )`. All what I do, is to copy it from one instance of Excel 2010 to another one (from one Excel 2010 window to another one). The result is that only the description/text/label of the hyperlink is inserted.

Comment: @Cyril I add some gifs, hope that explains it well

Answer (score 0):

There is a work around what solves the Excel to Excel copy problem but now I have a problem when pasting it in any other application

Based on the following posts I adapted the code mentioned there for VBA. The problem is now, that Windows now pastes the plain text in other application but it works flawless in Excel.
I added some GIFs at the end of this post for clarification.

---

[stackoverflow - Excel VBA code to copy a specific string to clipboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14219455/excel-vba-code-to-copy-a-specific-string-to-clipboard)
[Byte Comb Copy and Paste in VBA](http://bytecomb.com/copy-and-paste-in-vba/)
[stackoverflow - How do I copy formatted HTML string into a Clipboard for paste using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14613562/how-do-i-copy-formatted-html-string-into-a-clipboard-for-paste-using-c)
[Mike Stall's .NET Debugging Blog - Copying HTML on the clipboard](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jmstall/2007/01/21/copying-html-on-the-clipboard/)
The links above lead to the subroutine what puts the formated HTML link in the clipboard:

```
Public Sub CopyCellHyperlinkToClipboard(sLink As String, sDescription As String)
    Dim objData As Object
    On Error Resume Next
     ' this is a late bound MSForms.DataObject
    Set objData = CreateObject("New:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")

     ' copy current cell formula to clipboard
    With objData
        .SetText CreateHTMLString(sLink, sDescription)
        .PutInClipboard
    End With
End Sub
```

[stackoverflow - How to set HTML to clipboard in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13332377/how-to-set-html-to-clipboard-in-c)
[Mike Stall's .NET Debugging Blog - Copying HTML on the clipboard](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jmstall/2007/01/21/copying-html-on-the-clipboard/)
The links above lead to the function what creates the actual HTML string:

```
Function CreateHTMLString(sLink As String, sDescription As String)
    Dim sContextStart As String, sContextEnd As String, m_sDescription As String, sHtmlFragment As String, sData As String, sSourceURL As String

    m_sDescription = "Version:1.0" + Constants.vbCrLf _
                   + "StartHTML:aaaaaaaaaa" + Constants.vbCrLf _
                   + "EndHTML:bbbbbbbbbb" + Constants.vbCrLf _
                   + "StartFragment:cccccccccc" + Constants.vbCrLf _
                   + "EndFragment:dddddddddd" + Constants.vbCrLf
    sContextStart = "<HTML><BODY><!--StartFragment -->"
    'sSourceURL = "" + Constants.vbCrLf
    sHtmlFragment = "<A HREF=" + Strings.Chr(34) + sLink + Strings.Chr(34) + ">" + sDescription + "</A>"
    sContextEnd = "<!--EndFragment --></BODY></HTML>"

    sData = m_sDescription + sContextStart + sHtmlFragment + sContextEnd
    sData = Replace(sData, "aaaaaaaaaa", PadLeft(10, "0", Len(m_sDescription)))
    sData = Replace(sData, "bbbbbbbbbb", PadLeft(10, "0", Len(sData)))
    sData = Replace(sData, "cccccccccc", PadLeft(10, "0", Len(m_sDescription + sContextStart)))
    sData = Replace(sData, "dddddddddd", PadLeft(10, "0", Len(m_sDescription + sContextStart + sHtmlFragment)))
    'sData.Dump();
    CreateHTMLString = sData
End Function
```

Since padding isn't supported by VBA I created this function based on the the link below:
[stackoverflow - Any method equivalent to PadLeft/PadRight?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12060347/any-method-equivalent-to-padleft-padright)

```
Function PadLeft(iLength As Integer, cChar As String, sText As String)
    cChar = Left(cChar, 1)
    PadLeft = Right(String(iLength, cChar) & sText, iLength)

End Function
```

---

Insert a hyperlink from instance of Excel 2010 to another one, as you can see it insert only the label of the hyperlink: 
[image: Excel2Excel]
Insert a hyperlink in Excel in another application works flawless:
[image: Excel2App]
Therefore I wrote the code above. Now Excel2Excel works:
[image: Excel2Excel by VBA]
but it doesn't work for other applications:
[image: Excel2App by VBA]

Answer (score 0):

If you can create the link via VBA, it should circumvent the issue about needing to copy a link to the clipboard.

You would take your sheet you are creating links for and use a loop similar to:

```
With Sheets(A)
    .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Cells(1,2), Address:=.Cells(1,1), TextToDisplay:="Example" 
End With
```

This is a pretty general suggestion, and should allow you to look, e.g., .Cells(i,1) and .Cells(i,2) for the specific example.

Copying from one workbook to another, using a *full* hyperlink, rather than a cell that says =hyperlink(), will hopefully fix the issue.