# Copy List to clipboard for rich text pasting into Outlook

Tags: c#, outlook, clipboard, onenote

I have a list made up of three pieces: Text, url, long text (basically, it's a twitter handle, link to the tweet, text of the tweet).

I'm trying to figure out how to load that list into the clipboard so that when you paste it into standalone Outlook (or OneNote, I'm presuming it'll be the same solution), you end up with a clickable link made out of the first two pieces of data (ie MyHandle is an `<a href` to the tweet).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alina's answer was correct, but I do agree with Rob about it needing more information.

Basically, there isn't a way to do it directly, however, in [How do I copy formatted HTML string into a Clipboard for paste using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14613562/how-do-i-copy-formatted-html-string-into-a-clipboard-for-paste-using-c) there's a reference to the HTMLFragment Class at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2007/01/21/sample-code-html-clipboard.aspx. That Class, called by HtmlFragment.CopyToClipboard(insertString); does still happen to work for pasting formatted text into Outlook/OneNote.

Looking at the original code, Clipboard.SetText(insertString, TextDataFormat.Html);, I should have tested that first since the original post was erroring on the paste, not the Clipboard set, but, in the end, the HTMLFragement class works so, I'm happy. It's just a project for a single person so it was a bit of half-arsedness (not a lot of error checking or beauty in the ui.. I mean, heck, I did it as a winform rather than fluent/uwp). But, that's the answer:

Try Clipboard.SetText(insertString, TextDataFormat.Html); and if that doesn't work when you attempt to paste into the clipboard, move head into the HTMLFragment Class in http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2007/01/21/sample-code-html-clipboard.aspx and call it via HtmlFragment.CopyToClipboard(YOUR_HTML_STRING);

Answer (score 0):

You could copy formatted HTML string into a Clipboard for paste using the below code:

```
HtmlFragment.CopyToClipboard(insertString);
selected.Paste();
```

Reference :

[How do I copy formatted HTML string into a Clipboard for paste using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14613562/how-do-i-copy-formatted-html-string-into-a-clipboard-for-paste-using-c)

Comment: OK, The question is tagged [tag:c#], so what's with this VB code?

Comment: What does that do? How does it answer the question? Don't just blurt out code. Explain yourself! https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer